# Sound sensor for Arduino Uno

Tags: c, sensors, arduino-uno

I got a short time ago an Arduino Kit, and i am trying a little project. Using a Sound sensor i want to sequentially turn on 3 leds. Meaning one clap turns LED1, then a second one the second one and so on. Problem is that this happens only for LED 1 and LED2, and without waiting for the third clap the third LED turns on and without a 4th clap the lights go off, even though i am counting them and resetting the value from the sensor. 
I cannot understand why this code works for the first and second Leds but the 3rd and 4th stages are going automatically .
Thanks!

I tried the following code, but it works only for the first and second LED, when the counter is 0 and 1, when it reaches 2, or 3 it activates even though i am not activating the sensor.

```
int soundSensor=2;
int LED1=4;
int LED2=5;
int LED3=6;
int counter =0;
 int SensorData=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(soundSensor,INPUT);
 pinMode(LED1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(LED3,OUTPUT);
 counter = 0;


}

void loop() {


  SensorData=digitalRead(soundSensor); 


  if(SensorData==1 && counter == 0){    
        digitalWrite(LED1,HIGH);
        counter++;
        SensorData=2;
        delay(1000);
  }
  if(SensorData==1 && counter == 1){
        digitalWrite(LED2,HIGH);
        counter++;
        SensorData=2;
        delay(1000);
  }
    if(SensorData==1 && counter == 2){
        digitalWrite(LED3,HIGH);
        counter++;
        SensorData=2;
        delay(1000);  
     }
      if(SensorData==1 && counter == 3){
        digitalWrite(LED1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(LED2,LOW);
        digitalWrite(LED3,LOW);
        counter++;
        SensorData=2;
        delay(1000);
         counter =0;
     }

  }
```

Comment: There can be an issue with the sound sensor itself, or there might be a possibility that the Arduino is picking up some spike from the sensor on Digital pin. Try connecting a 0.1uF ceramic capacitor across Digital Input pin and Ground and let us know if it works! Also, try printing the value of `SensorData` variable on serial console after `SensorData=digitalRead(soundSensor);` to debug what actually is happening.

Comment: Hi! ,
Thank you for your answer. I did a quick reading of the SoundSensor and the value is 2 when i place it at the end of the if, as i set inside the If statement.  Therefore i suspected a problem with the code but i still do not understand why on the first 2 cases it works and not on the 3rd and 4th :(.
I will Try connecting a 0.1uF ceramic capacitor as you said and see what happens.
Thanks!